Why does the player sprite look under the yellow point sprite even if both at the same Z height of 0?
I went in the editor to the menu in the editor:  Edit > Project settings... > Tags and Layers and then added the Player and the YellowPoints in the Sorting Layers and then in the player object itself I set the Sorting Layer to Player and order to 0 and in the Yellow Point prefab set the Sorting Layer to the YellowPoints and order is 1.
But it didn't help much. The player is still moving under the yellow points. At least it looks like it is.




Higher Order Layer will be visible at Top
according your settings in layers ,
Player is visible Correctly below Yellow Coins
Change Order of layers in settings. That will do
